# java assembled binary varies depending of the order of the source files

Tags: java, class, assembly, compilation, javac

I'm using javac compiler and I've found it produces different resulting binary .class files depending on the order of the source files passed as parameter. In fact, it's a matter of compiling with ANT or MAVEN because they order the files differently.

Between 2 compilations there was differences. I've disassembled the code and I found the javac (optimizer?) was removing the deprecated java jsr/ret assembly instructions from one of the compilations.

I'm wondering if this behaviour it's the result of "implicit" compilation:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/solaris/javac.html#searching

- Anyone can explain this behaviour?
- How can I generate an "idempotent" compilation process in ANT and MAVEN where the order of the source files passed to the compiler doesn't matter?

Comment: Why do you care? Is there something that is getting broken?

Comment: Did you make sure both Ant and Maven are using the same javac compiler version with the same arguments? I have head that javac 6 is not using jsr/ret anymore, while javac 5 does for try-finally blocks.

Comment: I care because I'm curious (concerned) why java compiles differently. Anyway, if you have to validate the migration from ANT to MAVEN one thing you must do is to validate the compilation process are generating the same binary. Think if you change plugins like jibx that instrument code and you have to work with different versions of compiler plugins in maven.

Comment: Have you reproduced the problem without Ant/Maven? (changing order from javac commandline)

Comment: Yes. I've invoked explicitly the javac command and i confirm you the generated binary is different depending on the order of the source files to compile.

Answer (score 0):

You can get list of your sources and then sort it alphabetically, including full path. That would make it consistent between runs.

Comment: The thing it's with ANT and MAVEN you can specify the source folders, but they order the files differently. Ordering each source file in the task/pom would not be feasible.